# Binary multiplication of 11001000 and 10011010 - Different answer?

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I've run into a bit of an issue during my multiplication of these two binary values: $11001000\ (0.11001000 \times 2^2)$ and $10011010\ (0.10011010 \times 2^0)$. The answer I get when I did the calculations is $111110000101$, which I assumed would be $0.111110000101$. However, on the answer sheet, the answer is listed as $0.0111110000101$. Is there a reason why there is an added zero to the left?

I've attached a photo of the actual problem from my book
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X6RC.png), if that helps.

Comment: $(0.11001000 \times 2^2) \times (0.10011010 \times 2^0)$ should be something like $0.011\ldots \times 2^2 = 0.11\ldots \times 2^1$. That's also what is says.

Comment: You have a copy error. The photo from the book says ($0.0111\,1000\,0101\times2^2$), but your question misquotes the mantissa/significand as ($0.0111\,1100\,0010\,1$) (spaces added for clarity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
0.11001000 \times 2^2 
= (11001000 \times 2^{-8}) \times 2^2 
= 11001000 \times 2^{-6}
$$
and
$$
0.10011010 \times 2^0
= (10011010 \times 2^{-8}) \times 2^0
= 10011010 \times 2^{-8}.
$$

Therefore,
$$
(0.11001000 \times 2^2) \times (0.10011010 \times 2^0)
= (11001000 \times 2^{-6}) \times (10011010 \times 2^{-8})
\\
= (11001000 \times 10011010) \times (2^{-6} \times 2^{-8})
= 111110000101 \times 2^{-14}
\\
= 0.00111110000101
= 0.111110000101 \times 2^{-2}.
$$